# Maximum distribution of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, extreme-value-theorem

As the title says, I am searching for literature about the maximum distribution of the (stationary) Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process in **finite** time intervals [0,t]. Can anybody help me here?
Many thanks
Karl

Comment: The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is a.s unbounded. You can see this since it coincides in distribution with $e^{-t}B_{e^{2t}}/\sqrt{2}$ where $B_t$ is brownian motion and applying the law of iterated logorithms.

Comment: @pax I know this. I corrected my question. It is about finite time intervals!